# why would this error occur sometimes

Tags: android, sockets, ssl

I have an app that needs to connect to a webservice via https requests

I am using the EasySSLSocket library to do that

```
import org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.LayeredSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

/**
* This socket factory will create ssl socket that accepts self signed
* certificate
* 
* @author olamy
* @version $Id: EasySSLSocketFactory.java 765355 2009-04-15 20:59:07Z evenisse
*          $
* @since 1.2.3
*/
public class EasySSLSocketFactory implements LayeredSocketFactory {

private SSLContext sslcontext = null;

private static SSLContext createEasySSLContext() throws IOException {
    try {
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new EasyX509TrustManager(
                null) }, null);
        return context;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
    }
}

private SSLContext getSSLContext() throws IOException {
    if (this.sslcontext == null) {
        this.sslcontext = createEasySSLContext();
    }
    return this.sslcontext;
}

/**
 * @see org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory#connectSocket(java.net.Socket,
 *      String, int, java.net.InetAddress, int,
 *      org.apache.http.params.HttpParams)
 */
public Socket connectSocket(Socket sock, String host, int port,
        InetAddress localAddress, int localPort, HttpParams params)
        throws IOException, UnknownHostException, ConnectTimeoutException {
    int connTimeout = HttpConnectionParams.getConnectionTimeout(params);
    int soTimeout = HttpConnectionParams.getSoTimeout(params);

    InetSocketAddress remoteAddress = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
    SSLSocket sslsock = (SSLSocket) ((sock != null) ? sock : createSocket());

    if ((localAddress != null) || (localPort > 0)) {
        // we need to bind explicitly
        if (localPort < 0) {
            localPort = 0; // indicates "any"
        }
        InetSocketAddress isa = new InetSocketAddress(localAddress,
                localPort);
        sslsock.bind(isa);
    }

    sslsock.connect(remoteAddress, connTimeout);
    sslsock.setSoTimeout(soTimeout);
    return sslsock;

}

/**
 * @see org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory#createSocket()
 */
public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
    return getSSLContext().getSocketFactory().createSocket();
}

/**
 * @see org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory#isSecure(java.net.Socket)
 */
public boolean isSecure(Socket socket) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    return true;
}

/**
 * @see org.apache.http.conn.scheme.LayeredSocketFactory#createSocket(java.net.Socket,
 *      String, int, boolean)
 */
public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port,
        boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
    return getSSLContext().getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------
// javadoc in org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory says :
// Both Object.equals() and Object.hashCode() must be overridden
// for the correct operation of some connection managers
// -------------------------------------------------------------------

public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return ((obj != null) && obj.getClass().equals(
            EasySSLSocketFactory.class));
}

public int hashCode() {
    return EasySSLSocketFactory.class.hashCode();
}
```

}

```
public class EasyX509TrustManager
    implements X509TrustManager
{

private X509TrustManager standardTrustManager = null;

/**
 * Constructor for EasyX509TrustManager.
 */
public EasyX509TrustManager( KeyStore keystore )
    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException
{
    super();
    TrustManagerFactory factory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance( TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm() );
    factory.init( keystore );
    TrustManager[] trustmanagers = factory.getTrustManagers();
    if ( trustmanagers.length == 0 )
    {
        throw new NoSuchAlgorithmException( "no trust manager found" );
    }
    this.standardTrustManager = (X509TrustManager) trustmanagers[0];
}

/**
 * @see javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager#checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[],String authType)
 */
public void checkClientTrusted( X509Certificate[] certificates, String authType )
    throws CertificateException
{
    standardTrustManager.checkClientTrusted( certificates, authType );
}

/**
 * @see javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager#checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[],String authType)
 */
public void checkServerTrusted( X509Certificate[] certificates, String authType )
    throws CertificateException
{
    if ( ( certificates != null ) && ( certificates.length == 1 ) )
    {
        certificates[0].checkValidity();
    }
    else
    {
        standardTrustManager.checkServerTrusted( certificates, authType );
    }
}

/**
 * @see javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager#getAcceptedIssuers()
 */
public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers()
{
    return this.standardTrustManager.getAcceptedIssuers();
}
```

}

and here is how i connect to the socket

```
    private static HttpClient getHttpClient() {
    if(manager == null) {
        // sets up parameters
        clientParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(clientParams, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(clientParams, HTTP.UTF_8);
        clientParams.setBooleanParameter(HttpProtocolParams.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, false);
        // registers schemes for both http and https
        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(new Scheme(HTTP_PREFIX, PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), HTTP_PORT));
        registry.register(new Scheme(HTTPS_PREFIX, new EasySSLSocketFactory(), HTTPS_PORT));
        manager = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(clientParams, registry);
        }
        return new DefaultHttpClient(manager, clientParams);
}
```

why on some devices i am getting this error :

```
12-12 08:59:01.565 E/HTTPUtils(23906): javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Read error: ssl=0x5903ef90: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
12-12 08:59:01.565 E/HTTPUtils(23906): at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native Method)
12-12 08:59:01.565 E/HTTPUtils(23906): at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:651)
12-12 08:59:01.565 E/HTTPUtils(23906): at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
12-12 08:59:01.565 E/HTTPUtils(23906): at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:191)
12-12 08:59:01.565 E/HTTPUtils(23906): at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:82)
12-12 08:59:01.565 E/HTTPUtils(23906): at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:174)
12-12 08:59:01.565 E/HTTPUtils(23906): at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:180)
12-12 08:59:01.565 E/HTTPUtils(23906): at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:235)
12-12 08:59:01.565 E/HTTPUtils(23906): at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:259)
12-12 08:59:01.565 E/HTTPUtils(23906): at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:279)
12-12 08:59:01.565 E/HTTPUtils(23906): at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
12-12 08:59:01.565 E/HTTPUtils(23906): at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:428)
12-12 08:59:01.565 E/HTTPUtils(23906): at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:670)
12-12 08:59:01.565 E/HTTPUtils(23906): at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
12-12 08:59:01.565 E/HTTPUtils(23906): at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
```

Answer (score 0):

In mobile world it is quite often the reason is just cellular network the client app operates on. Just be ready to retry if your request failed.